# How I can revert database changes after running the tests Yii2 Codeception

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

I want to know if there is any method that can help me with my problem. My Codeception tests will run on a dev environment and I want to revert database after running the tests to the initial content. Does someone knows how I can do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How in codeception to make rollback a database if the test failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582326/how-in-codeception-to-make-rollback-a-database-if-the-test-failed)

Comment: You shouldn't run tests in development environment. The best practice is to have independent environment for tests and use fixtures to fill it with data for tests. That's because you should run tests in controlled environment not in  environment where you can have some random data from development.